# Replace/sync only certain lines using Bash, SSH and rsync

Tags: bash, ssh, rsync

I am looking for a quick and dirty one-liner to sync only certain settings in remote config files. Need to preserve what's unique and sync generic settings. Example:

Config1.conf:

```
HOSTNAME=COMP1
IP=10.10.13.10

LOCATION=SITE_A
BUILDING=DEPT_IT
ROOM=COMP_LAB1
```

Remote-Config2.txt:

```
HOSTNAME=COMP2
IP=10.10.13.11

LOCATION=FOO
BUILDING=BAR
ROOM=BAZ
```

I need to sync or copy replace only the **bottom 3 lines** over ssh. The line numbers are predictable, by the way. Always lines 4,5 and 6 in this case.

Here's a **working** idea that is missing one piece (a standard replacement for the non-standard utility I used to replace the vars in the local conf):

```
for var in $(ssh root@10.10.8.12 'sed -n "4,6p" /etc/conf1.conf');do <missing piece> ${var/=*}=${var/*=} local-conf.conf; done
```

So this uses variable expansion and a non-standard utility but needs like a sed or Perl routine to replace the info in the local conf.

**Update**
The last line of code actually works. Tested and works! However -- the missing piece is a custom non-standard utility. I'm asking if someone can think of something, using standard Linux tools, to replace that.

One solution would be to take the left side and match, then replace the right side. This is basically what that utility does. Looks for the variable in the conf then sets it. Using variable expansion is one way (shown).

Comment: You need to rsync the whole config to the remote under a temp name (or bring the remote to the local under a temp name), then you can use ssh to put a new config together. Something like `rsync Config1.conf remote:/tmp/temp1.conf`, then create the new config `ssh remote 'head -n+2 /tmp/temp1.conf > /tmp/tempnew.conf'`, then `ssh remote 'tail -n+3 remote:/path/to/Config2.txt >> /tmp/tempnew.conf'` Then you can copy /tmp/tempnew.conf to Config2.txt after you verify.

Comment: This is a good solution but I'm looking for a solution with less operations. Thanks though!

Comment: Why was this downvoted? It's a reasonable and practical issue -- I've presented conceptually how it would/could work. I've shown code -- Incidentally, the last line of code I put up actually works, but relies on a non-standard utility. I need something to put in place of that utility. I didn't even use the much maligned `eval`. So what gives?

Comment: You have a bunch of wet-behind-the-ears wanna-be people who make themselves feel more important by downvoting questions rather than doing what this site is here for and actually trying to help someone... It's sad... As to your approach, I like the thought, but no matter how you slice it, it still boils down to a multi-line substitution, that generally requires and intermediate temp file. (don't take the downvote personally, just consider the source...)

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative solution that does not require the command to have special knowledge of the file contents:

1. Take a copy of the files you want to sync. Then, in the copy, deliberately vandalise (arbitrarily modify) the lines you do *not* want synced. It doesn't matter what they say as long as there are the same number of lines and they'll never match the actual file contents. Have some fun. This becomes your **base** version. Your example might look like this:

   ```
   HOSTNAME=foo
   IP=bar

   LOCATION=SITE_A
   BUILDING=DEPT_IT
   ROOM=COMP_LAB1
   ```
2. `rsync` the remote files into a temporary location. This is the **remote** version.
3. For each file, take a three-way diff.

   ```
   diff3 -3 <localfile> <basefile> <remotefile>
   ```

   The output of `diff3` is an "ed script" that decribes what edits to make to the local file so that it would look like the remote file.

   The `-3` option tells it to only output the non-conflicting differences. This is why we vandalised the base files in the first place: so those lines *would* have conflicts.
4. Once you have the ed script for a file, you can visually check it, if you choose, and then apply the update using `patch`:

   ```
   cat <ed-script> | patch --ed <localfile>
   ```

So, to do this recursively, you might have:

```
cd $localdir
for file in `find . -type f`; do
    diff3 -3 "$file" "$basedir/$file" "$remotedir/$file" | patch --ed "$file"
done
```

You probably need to add some checks that the base and remote files actually exist.

Comment: This is more along the lines of what I'm looking for. I will work through this and see how it goes. Thanks!